# 3 phase to single phase UPS 10 kva

Tags: ups

I have a 3 phase to single phase ups 10kva. The Input voltage required is 332v to 444v/ 3 phase voltage with an output of 220-240v single phase. I have an external battery bank of 2v x 12 connected in series to make up 24v. My D.C. Voltage is still not enough to run the ups inverter when my 3 phase supply goes off. Can I be able to get a D.C. To D.C. Converter from 24v to 400v with a high amperage. Instead of adding more Battries.

Comment: "Converter from 24v to 400v with a high amperage." How high do you expect current will be at 24V? Quiescent, nominal and full load? And what are the specs for your battery bank?

Comment: Am expecting the load to draw maximum of 50Amps

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 3 phase to single phase UPS 10 kVA [note capitals].

OK. Why not tell use the make and model and give a link to the datasheet?

> The input voltage required is 332 V to 444 V / 3 phase voltage with an output of 220 - 240 V single phase.

OK.

> I have an external battery bank of 2 V x 12 connected in series to make up 24 V.

Why not tell us the Ah rating and maximum discharge current of the cells? That will be crucial.

> My D.C. Voltage is still not enough to run the ups inverter when my 3 phase supply goes off.

What voltage does it need?

> Can I be able to get a D.C. To D.C. converter from 24 V to 400 V with a high amperage. Instead of adding more batteries.

Sure you can. Will it be efficient? Probably not. Will it work? Maybe.

To get 10 kVA at 24 V would require \$ I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {10000}{24} = 400 \ \text A \$ at 100% efficiency. The actual current will increase inversely with decreasing efficiency.

Comment: @Steven 400A from 24VDC! That's like a big starting motor running continuously and cranking a motor which do not start.  How long the batteries do stand that?